# Cannot animate viewport/render visibility

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view

I'm trying to animate a collection in 2.8 so that it hides at a certain point in the viewport and the render but when I hover over either icon it says that "hide_viewport/render cannot be animated." Do I have to enable something in user settings?[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can animate the "Show in Render" and "Show in Viewports" flags here:
[image]

For entire collection, you can link the Animation Data from one object to the others. Note that this will override other keyframes set on destination objects.

[image]

Comment: That's for a single object. What about a collection?

Comment: the question was for collection, not for workarounds.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, as indicated in my answer: "For entire collection, you can link the Animation Data from one object to the others. Note that this will override other keyframes set on destination objects."